# AngularJS Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider (where is uiViewScrollProvider)

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-config

Using AngularJS 1.4.8, how does one obtain a reference to uiViewScrollProvider (it's not found at injection time):

```
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$uiViewScrollProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $uiViewScrollProvider) {
```

Comment: have you injected `ui.router` module in your application with `angular-ui-router.js` file?

Comment: I'm using ngRoute - https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route

Comment: `$uiViewScrollProvider` is a part of AngularUI Router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Answer (score 1):

`uiViewScrollProvider` belongs to [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) not `ngRoute`.

Change your app like this,

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.router']);
```